# Why does Pandas iterate over DataFrame columns by default?

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to understand the design rationale behind some of Pandas' features.

If I have a DataFrame with 3560 rows and 18 columns, then

```
len(frame)
```

is 3560, but

```
len([a for a in frame])
```

is 18.

Maybe this feels natural to someone coming from R; to me it doesn't feel very 'Pythonic'.  Is there an introduction to the underlying design rationales for Pandas somewhere?

Comment: Good question! I would intuitively expect `len` to be consistent with iterating... :-/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A DataFrame is primarily a column-based data structure.
Under the hood, the data inside the DataFrame is stored in blocks. Roughly speaking there is one block for each dtype.
*Each column has one dtype*. So accessing a column can be done by selecting the appropriate column from a single block. In contrast, selecting a single row requires selecting the appropriate row from each block and then forming a new Series and copying the data from each block's row into the Series.
Thus, iterating through rows of a DataFrame is (under the hood) not as natural a process as iterating through columns.

If you need to iterate through the rows, you still can, however, by calling `df.iterrows()`. You should avoid using `df.iterrows` if possible for the same reason why it's unnatural -- it requires copying which makes the process slower than iterating through columns.

Answer (score 5):

There's a decent explanation in the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/basics.html#iteration) - iteration for Pandas DataFrames is meant to be "dict-like," so the iteration is over the keys (the columns).

Arguably it's a little confusing that iteration for Series is over the values, but as the docs note, that's because they are are more "array-like".