# Operations on every row in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to iterate through every row in a pandas DataFrame, and do something with the elements in each row.

Right now I have

```
for row in df.iterrows(): 
    if row['col'] > 1.5:
        doSomething
```

but it tells me that the 'tuple indices must be integers, not str' . How do I access the column that I want in a certain row?

Comment: I would question why do it this way? The whole point of using pandas is to try to perform operations on the whole series or dataframe. If all you wanted to do was perform some operation just on the rows that met that criteria then `df.loc[df['col']>1.5, 'col'] = doSomething` would achieve the same result and will be blisteringly fast as it will be vectorised

Comment: okay, great. where would i put an alternate doSomething if it wasn't greater than 1.5?

Comment: you can either do a `np.where` or just 2 statements so either `df['col'] = np.where(df['col'] > 1.5, doSomething, doSomethingElse)` or add another statement for the opposite condition `df.loc[df['col'] <=1.5, 'col'] = doSomethingElse`

Comment: The point here is to avoid looping unless there is no way to avoid it, at the moment your code snippet doesn't specify what you really want to do so we can only guess but it's likely that you don't want to loop over the rows and you really should try to use a vectorised method where possible

Answer (score 8):

You can use `apply` function with option `axis=1`. For example:

```
def my_function(row):
    if row['col'] > 1.5:
        doSomething()
    else:
        doSomethingElse()

my_df.apply(my_function, axis=1)
```

[source](http://jonathansoma.com/lede/foundations/classes/pandas%20columns%20and%20functions/apply-a-function-to-every-row-in-a-pandas-dataframe/)

Comment: This is the best answer. Because it is the most efficient. Using for loop takes a lot more time. using vector functions instead of for loop takes less time to compute.
Watch this [video](https://youtu.be/WF9n_19V08g) by Udacity how to optimize code using vector functions of pandas and NumPy. https://youtu.be/WF9n_19V08g

Answer (score 7):

Probably the simplest solution is to use the **APPLYMAP** or **APPLY** fucntions which applies the function to every data value in the entire data set.

You can execute this in a few ways:

```
df.applymap(someFunction)
```

or

```
df[["YourColumns"]].apply(someFunction)
```

The Links are below:

[ApplyMap Docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html)

[Apply Docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

Answer (score 4):

[`iterrows`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) yields (index, Series) pairs. Therefore, use:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows(): 
    if row['col'] > 1.5:
        doSomething
```

Note, however, that [a DataFrame is a primarily column-based data structure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25918149/190597), so
you'll get better performance if you can structure your code around column-wise
operations, instead of row-wise operations.

Comment: thanks! These pairs are immutable, correct? Is there a way I could rewrite the element in the column?

Comment: EdChum's method, `df.loc[df['col']>1.5, 'col'] = doSomething` would be better, assuming `doSomething` is a number. If not, you'll have to explain in more detail what `doSomething` is.