# Row wise operation in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe as

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
  "First": ['First1', 'First2', 'First3'],
  "Secnd": ['Secnd1', 'Secnd2', 'Secnd3']
)
df.index = ['Row1', 'Row2', 'Row3']
```

I would like to  have a `lambda` function in `apply` method to create a list of dictionary (including index item) as below

```
[
  {'Row1': ['First1', 'Secnd1']},
  {'Row2': ['First2', 'Secnd2']},
  {'Row3': ['First3', 'Secnd3']},
]
```

If I use something like `.apply(lambda x: <some operation>)` here, `x` does not include the index rather the values.

Cheers,
DD

Comment: Please check here, maybe it will solve your issue as the question are same.
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26243993/operations-on-every-row-in-pandas-dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26243993/operations-on-every-row-in-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand Hans Bambel's answer to get the exact desired output:

```
[{k: list(v.values())} for k, v in df.to_dict('index').items()]
```

Comment: True, thanks for the extension! I did not see that wanted to have a list instead of a dict!

Answer (score 3):

You don't need apply here. You can just use the to_dict() function with the "index" argument:

```
df.to_dict("index")
```

This gives the output:

```
{'Row1': {'First': 'First1', 'Secnd': 'Secnd1'}, 
'Row2': {'First': 'First2', 'Secnd': 'Secnd2'}, 
'Row3': {'First': 'First3', 'Secnd': 'Secnd3'}}
```