# What is the trick behind the map function in Python?

Tags: python, optimization, dictionary, pandas

I have a pandas data-frame and a function of N arguments. Now, for each row I would like to use values from N columns as input for the function and the output of the function I would like to save in an additional column. I can do it in a "direct" way:

```
inds = []
d = {}
for ind, row in df.iterrows():
   inds.append(ind)
   d[ind] = my_func(row.col1, row.col2, row.col3)
df['out_col'] = pandas.Series(d, index = inds)
```

However, it is much more faster to use the following:

```
df['out_col'] = map(my_func, df.col1, df.col2, df.col3)
```

Why is it much more faster then the "straightforward" solution. What trick the map function uses to be so fast?

Comment: Can you compare the speed when using `df.itertuples()` instead of `df.iterrows`?

Comment: The right-hand side of `df['out_col'] = map(my_func, row.col1, row.col2, row.col3)` is one value (dependent on `row`). But assigning that to `df['out_col']` means the whole column will get the same value. So it will not do the same thing as `d[ind] = my_func(row.col1, row.col2, row.col3)` followed by `df['out_col'] = pandas.Series(d, index = inds)` outside the loop. I don't think you are comparing apples to apples.

Comment: A DataFrame is [primarily a column-based data structure](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25918149/190597). Computation will generally be faster if you operate on whole columns instead of row-by-row.

Comment: It is not `map` that is fast, but `iterrows` that is very slow. You can use `itertuples` and will get something almost as fast as `map`, but as @unutbu says, you should try to see if you can apply this function on the whole columns.