# python - possible to apply percentile cuts to each column in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization, quantile

Is it possible to put percentile cuts on all columns of a dataframe with using a loop? This is how I am doing it now:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,5))
df_q = pd.DataFrame()

for i in list(range(len(df.columns))):
    df_q[i] = pd.qcut(df[i], 5, labels=list(range(5)))
```

I am hoping there is a slick pandas solution for this to avoid the use of a loop.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pd.qcut` accepts an 1D array or Series as its argument. To apply `pd.qcut` to every column requires multiple calls to `pd.qcut`. So no matter how you dress it up, there will be a loop -- either explicit or implicit.

You could for example, use `apply` to call `pd.qcut` for each column:

```
In [46]: df.apply(lambda x: pd.qcut(x, 5, labels=list(range(5))), axis=0)
Out[46]: 
   0  1  2  3  4
0  4  0  3  0  3
1  0  0  2  3  0
2  3  4  1  2  3
3  4  1  1  1  4
4  3  2  2  4  1
5  2  4  3  0  1
6  2  3  0  4  4
7  1  3  4  2  2
8  0  1  4  3  0
9  1  2  0  1  2
```

but under the hood, `df.apply` is using a `for-loop`, so it really isn't very different than your `for-loop`:

```
df_q = pd.DataFrame()
for col in df:
    df_q[col] = pd.qcut(df[col], 5, labels=list(range(5)))
```

---

```
In [47]: %timeit df.apply(lambda x: pd.qcut(x, 5, labels=list(range(5))), axis=0)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.9 ms per loop

In [48]: %%timeit
    df_q = pd.DataFrame()
    for col in df:
        df_q[col] = pd.qcut(df[col], 5, labels=list(range(5)))
100 loops, best of 3: 2.95 ms per loop
```

---

Note that

```
for i in list(range(len(df.columns))):
```

will only work if the columns of `df` happen to be sequential integers starting at 0.
It is more robust to use

```
for col in df:
```

to iterate over the columns of the DataFrame.

Comment: how would you call it for rows?

Comment: @thomas.mac: Change `axis=0` to `axis=1` to apply the function to rows.

Comment: Note, however, that DataFrames are [primarily column-based](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25918149/190597), so if you have a lot of row-based numeric calculations, you might want to consider transposing your DataFrame: `df = df.T` so they become column-based calculations.