# Subtract two rows based on condition in Python Pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I'm working with a data set where I have time and the concentration of several
different species of microorganism with replicates, so it's just a time column
and a bunch of numbers for the sake of this question. I was taking measurements
every two hours and sometimes I would take two measurements consecutively and
these measurements would have timestamps very similar to each other. For those
similar timestamps, I would like to take the average of the two rows for all the
columns and return those averages into a new data frame where the two values
were placed before.

Here is what the dataframe looks like. The timestamps have been converted into
numerical values because the relative time/date is irrelevant. You can see an
example of what I'm talking about, where there are two very similar times at the
9th and 10th index

```
      Time        A1       A2       A3
 0    0.000069    118.0    108.0    70.0
 1    0.087049    189.0    54.0     89.0
 2    0.156551    154.0    122.0    107.0
 3    0.721516    129.0    148.0    148.0
 4    0.789329    143.0    162.0    212.0
 5    0.882743    227.0    229.0    149.0
 6    0.964907    208.0    255.0    241.0
 7    1.041424    200.0    241.0    222.0
 8    1.731806    733.0    838.0    825.0
 9    1.794340    804.0    996.0    954.0
10    1.794769    861.0    987.0    1138.0
```

It seems obvious to round the numbers in the time column to a sensible value,
whereby I can use a `groupby()` function (if I actually needed to group them) and
then average the "duplicate" values, but I've gone down a new philosophical road
where I would like to use the pandas `iterrows()` function to go through the
rows, 1 by 1, and compare every two consecutive rows and apply a condition to
them to achieve the same result. I've arrived at something like this, which has
no error code but doesn't seem to do anything.

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    row2 = row + 1 #I feel like this line is the crux of the problem
    if row2.Time - row.Time >= 0.1:
        row = (row2 + row)/2
    else:
        row = row
```

Out of curiosity, I'd be curious to know which is faster, the groupby and
average way or the for loop and average way. Maybe there's a nifty lamba
function way to do this as well? I've searched extensively for this type of
thing and I would love to see what you all can come up with.

Cheers

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are some general tips:

- Prefer vectorized computations over python for-loops. For example, calling `df['Time'].diff()` is much faster than computing `row2['Time'] - row1['Time']` in a loop. The vectorized computation will always beat the for-loop computation for sufficiently large `N` where `N` is the number of iterations required by the `for-loop`.
- [Prefer column-based operations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25918149/190597) over row-based operations
- Prefer fewer operations on large arrays over many operations on smaller arrays.

As a demonstration of the principles, consider these two different ways of computing the desired result:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A1': [118.0, 189.0, 154.0, 129.0, 143.0, 227.0, 208.0, 200.0, 733.0, 804.0, 861.0], 'A2': [108.0, 54.0, 122.0, 148.0, 162.0, 229.0, 255.0, 241.0, 838.0, 996.0, 987.0], 'A3': [70.0, 89.0, 107.0, 148.0, 212.0, 149.0, 241.0, 222.0, 825.0, 954.0, 1138.0], 'Time': [6.8999999999999997e-05, 0.087049000000000001, 0.156551, 0.72151599999999994, 0.78932899999999995, 0.88274300000000006, 0.96490699999999996, 1.0414239999999999, 1.7318060000000002, 1.79434, 1.7947689999999998]}) 

def using_loop(df):
    for i in range(len(df)-1):
        row1, row2 = df.iloc[i], df.iloc[i+1]
        if row2['Time'] - row1['Time'] >= 0.1:
            df.iloc[i] = (row2 + row1)/2
    return df

def using_column_based_operations(df):
    mask = df['Time'].diff() >= 0.1
    prior = mask.shift(-1).fillna(False)
    df.loc[prior] = (df.loc[mask].values+df.loc[prior].values)/2
    return df

In [220]: using_loop(df).equals(using_column_based_operations(df))
Out[220]: True
```

---

Here is a benchmark using IPython's `%%timeit` function which shows `using_column_based_operations` is thousands of times faster than `using_loop` when `nrows` is 10**4. As `nrows` increases, the speed advantage of `using_column_based_operations` increases.

```
In [216]: nrows, ncols = 10**4, 4

In [217]: %%timeit df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((nrows, ncols)), columns=['Time', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3'])
   .....: using_loop(df)
   .....: 
1 loop, best of 3: 3.02 s per loop

In [218]: %%timeit df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((nrows, ncols)), columns=['Time', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3'])
   .....: using_column_based_operations(df)
   .....: 
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.91 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thanks for such a quick response! The improvement with the vectorized way is palpable. Thanks for helping solve this and entertaining my curiosity. Million thanks. -Cheers!