# Interpolate PANDAS df

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation

I know this subject was brought up a few times on stack overflow, however I'm still stumbling upon an interpolation problem.

I have a complex dataframe of a set of columns, which could look something like this if simplified:

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,7), columns=[402.3, 407.2, 412.3, 415.8, 419.9, 423.5, 428.3])
wl     = np.array([400.0, 408.2, 412.5, 417.2, 420.5, 423.3, 425.0])
```

So what I need to do is to interpolate column-wise, to the new assigned values of cols (wl), for each row.

And how to get the new dataframe with columns ONLY containing values presented in the wl array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `reindex` to include `wl` as new columns (whose values will be filled with NaNs). 
Then use `interpolate(axis=1)` to interpolate across the columns.
Strictly speaking interpolation is only done *between* known values.
You could, however, use `limit_direction='both'` to *fill* NaN edge values in both the forward and backward directions:

```
>>> df_new.reindex(columns=df_new.columns.union(wl)).interpolate(axis=1, limit_direction='both')
      400.0     402.3     407.2     408.2     412.3     412.5     415.8     417.2     419.9     420.5     423.3     423.5     425.0     428.3
0  0.342346  0.342346  1.502418  1.102496  0.702573  0.379089  0.055606 -0.135563 -0.326732 -0.022298  0.282135  0.586569  0.164917 -0.256734
1 -0.220773 -0.220773 -0.567199 -0.789194 -1.011190 -0.485832  0.039526 -0.426771 -0.893069 -0.191818  0.509432  1.210683  0.414023 -0.382636
2  0.078147  0.078147  0.335040 -0.146892 -0.628824 -0.280976  0.066873 -0.881153 -1.829178 -0.960608 -0.092038  0.776532  0.458758  0.140985
3 -0.792214 -0.792214  0.254805  0.027573 -0.199659 -1.173250 -2.146841 -1.421482 -0.696124 -0.073018  0.550088  1.173194 -0.049967 -1.273128
4 -0.485818 -0.485818  0.019046 -1.421351 -2.861747 -1.020571  0.820605  0.097722 -0.625160 -0.782700 -0.940241 -1.097781 -0.809617 -0.521453
```

Note that Pandas DataFrames store values in a [primarily column-based](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25918149/190597) data structure. So computations are generally more efficient when done column-wise, not row-wise. Therefore, it might be better to transpose your dataframe:

```
df = df_new.T
```

and then proceed similarly as described above:

```
df = df.reindex(index=df.index.union(wl))
df = df.interpolate(limit_direction='both')
```

---

If you want to extrapolate edge values, you could use [`scipy.interpolate.interp1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html) with :
`fill_value='extrapolate'`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.interpolate as interpolate
np.random.seed(2018)

df_new = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,7), columns=[402.3, 407.2, 412.3, 415.8, 419.9, 423.5, 428.3])
wl = np.array([400.0, 408.2, 412.5, 417.2, 420.5, 423.3, 425.0, 500])

x = df_new.columns
y = df_new.values
newx = x.union(wl)
result = pd.DataFrame(
    interpolate.interp1d(x, y, fill_value='extrapolate')(newx),
    columns=newx)
```

yields

```
      400.0     402.3     407.2     408.2     412.3     412.5     415.8     417.2     419.9     420.5     423.3     423.5     425.0     428.3      500.0
0 -0.679793 -0.276768  0.581851  0.889017  2.148399  1.952520 -1.279487 -0.671080  0.502277  0.561236  0.836376  0.856029  0.543898 -0.142790 -15.062654
1  0.484717  0.110079 -0.688065 -0.468138  0.433564  0.437944  0.510221  0.279613 -0.165131 -0.362906 -1.285854 -1.351779 -0.758526  0.546631  28.904127
2  1.303039  1.230655  1.076446  0.628001 -1.210625 -1.158971 -0.306677 -0.563028 -1.057419 -0.814173  0.320975  0.402057  0.366778  0.289165  -1.397156
3  2.385057  1.282733 -1.065696 -1.191370 -1.706633 -1.618985 -0.172797 -0.092039  0.063710  0.114863  0.353577  0.370628 -0.246613 -1.604543 -31.108665
4 -3.360837 -2.165729  0.380370  0.251572 -0.276501 -0.293597 -0.575682 -0.235060  0.421854  0.469009  0.689062  0.704780  0.498724  0.045401  -9.804075
```

---

If you wish to create a DataFrame containing only the `wl` columns, you could sub-select those columns using `result[wl]`, or you could simplying interpolate only at the `wl` values:

```
result_wl = pd.DataFrame(
    interpolate.interp1d(x, y, fill_value='extrapolate')(wl),
    columns=wl)
```

Comment: this is great, thanks! the only problem I have is that the limit_direction doesn't work for the lower limit. I get NaN values .... any hints why this might have happened?

Comment: There must be some difference between your actual DataFrame and the toy one shown here. I'm sorry to say I'm not succeeding in guessing what that difference might be. But maybe first we should pin down the behavior you actually want. Do you want to merely forward- and backward-fill NaNs on the edges? (That should be what `limit_direction='both'` is doing), or do you want to *extrapolate* values? If so, I think I would have to revise my post since `df.interpolate` won't do that. Instead, I think you may need `scipy.interpolate.interp1d(..., fill_value='extrapolate')`.

Comment: If you can construct a (hopefully simple) runnable example which demonstrates the problem, I or someone here can probably figure out how to fix it.

Comment: No idea what the problem could be because I use the very same example before implementing it on the large data set. But I truly appreciate your help, the answer was super helpful, many thanks for that! You're right, I might use the extrapolate from scipy to solve the issue indeed.

Comment: but how do you then use only the columns of the wl array as your new dataframe?

Comment: @PEBKAC: Either sub-select the `wl` columns using `result[wl]` or, if you know that these are the only columns you want, you could construct this DataFrame directly by interpolating only at the `wl` values. I've edited the post above to show what I mean.

Comment: `df_new.reindex(columns=df_new.columns.union(wl)).interpolate(axis=1, limit_direction='both')[wl]` - just tried adding [wl] at the end of your suggestion and it also works.